# Is there any difference in behaviour between auth/credentials and auth/basic?

Tags: servicestack

We have two separate websites which essentially share the same UserAuth data store. We want to provide the user with a link from one to the other without requiring them to login again.

At the moment we currently make a call to the target website's API: /auth/credentials which sets up the session and allows us to then redirect the user, bypassing the need go through the login screen. Great.

As far as I can tell /auth/basic should do exactly the same thing. However, the response from the API call is the same but when redirected the user ends up at the login page.

Have I missed something?

Version: 4.5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [not the same](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#credentials-auth-providers), the BasicAuthProvider enables HTTP’s [Basic Access Authentication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and is a [per Request Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers).

Comment: Credentials means they authenticate using Username/Password but how they do that is very different, only the CredentialsAuthProvider uses standard Request params in clear text, Basic and Digest Auth implement their respective HTTP Auth protocols.

Comment: @AlanS Why you would think that? If they had the same behavior there's no reason why they'd exist. They're different providers implementing different protocols and as documented Basic/Digest Auth are per-request Auth Providers which inherently have different behavior.

Comment: @AlanS The behavior of the [Session and per-request Auth providers are well documented](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#session-authentication-overview). Per Request Auth Providers like Basic Auth do not perform an explicit Authentication step, they authenticate per request, i.e. there is no authentication request to the `/auth/basic` endpoint, Authentication is added to HTTP Authorization Header **per request** as per the HTTP Basic Auth [RFC 7617 Standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617).